# Quicktime Streaming and protecting movies?

Tags: mac-osx-server, video-streaming, video

I am setting up a Quicktime Streaming server on OS X 10.6 so users can view movies that I make. I want to ensure that they cannot steal the movies however.

Two questions arise on how would I do this?

1. What permissions would I give the directory that contain the moves so one cannot use a web grabber to steal the content?
2. How do I prevent a Right click and "Save as..."?

Answer (score 0):

1. If a client can stream the movies, then you need to have read permissions on that folder. if they have read permissions on the folder, they can steal the content.
2. That's a question best answered on [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

Long story short: If it's on the internet, someone else can download it. Even the most sophisticated methods (RTMPE comes to mind) can be stolen by anyone with a demo copy of [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/).